# Can an interrupt routine not handle adding variable to an array?

Tags: arduino, interrupt, esp32

I have 2 input pins tied together as interrupts, 1 for high edge trigger and 1 for low edge trigger of VPW signal. Both interrupt routines are the same one starts a timer on high the other starts a timer on low. This is the high interrupt routine:

```
void CountH()
{
    digitalWrite(txPin, HIGH);
    THstart = micros();
    TLstop = micros();
    TLtime = (TLstop - TLstart);
    YY = YY + 1;
}
```

This works, as the other `CountL()` interrupt started the timer, but screws up if I add

```
DL[YY] = TLtime
```

to the routine. And I have to add to the array after interrupt ends, in regular loop. How can I add that one line to the interrupt?

Comment: Is the `YY` variable volatile?

Comment: IT's just : int XX = 0;
int YY = 0;
int DX[500];  // High
int DY[500];  // Low

Comment: Variables used inside of program and interrupt handlers must be volatile. Otherwise it can be completely optimized out or readed to the register and never updated and so on (because compiler doesn't know, the variable can be changed from the outside)

Comment: That sounds like probably my problem, I'm an electronics engineer not programmer, thank you KIIV, for taking the time, what comes around goes around.. I'll look into Volatile...

Comment: Yes, That was my one of my problems, the other being that I live in 2018, and only assumed that C and C++ developers would too....

Comment: @KIIV this should be an answer, not a comment :)